# cannot run apache and mysql in xampp

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

i am trying to install xampp on my system with windows 10 since yesterday.whenever i opened xampp control panel it disabled apache and mysql buttons.After further exploring i noticed that when control panel is opened these two files disappear while right after installation these are present.

```
xampp/apache/bin/httpd.exe
```

and

```
xampp/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe
```

I have turned off the firewall too.There is nothing running on ports 80 and 443 and also i have tried starting everything with administrative privilege.

Can anyone suggest a solution.

**Note:**I dont have enough reputation to post an image.but control panel says this:

```
12:09:04 PM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:09:04 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:09:04 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:09:04 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:09:04 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:09:04 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:09:04 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

and no PIDs or ports are assigned yet.

Comment: mysql and apache have an error log, check there for clues

Comment: both logs are empty

Comment: please post an image of your panel, there should be a pid and a port used if all goes accourding to plan.

Comment: i cant post image because of not enough reputation but have posted panel log.please see edited post.

Comment: My guess is that with all your installations is something really wrong. if you have not to much installed in the last time go back with stem recovery point and start a new

Comment: i have uninstalled and reinstalled xampp many times but can't fix this issue.

Comment: i have understand that is why i reconede to do a windows system recovery see https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-system-restore-windows-10

Comment: share `xampp/apache/bin/httpd.exe -t` command output for review.